# Which App-ID do I use for a RATE button

Tags: ios, button, app-store, rate

I have 2 App-ID's. One is the Bundle Identifier that's considered an App-ID that I found in Certificates,Identifies & Profiles. The other App-ID is a 9 digit number that I found in iTunes Connect in between the app icon and version.

I'm creating a RATE button.

I read on this website to use the BELOW code but i'm uncertain if this is all that's needed?

```
-(IBAction)ratebutton:{ 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL ULRWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/app/yourID"]];
}
```

As for the link, i've also read to use
 "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/yourID"

1) Which of the above two links is the correct one? I need the code to work for iOS 7 and iOS 8.

2) Is the above code really all that's needed to direct the user to MY specific page where my app will be instead of a random page in App store?

3)Which is the App-ID to use in Rate button link? Is it Bundle Identifier or the 9 digit number in iTunes connect between the app icon and version?

Comment: Use the iTunesConnect id for the app. And if you want to show your App Store page look into using `SKStoreProductViewController` instead of launching a URL.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the AppID you got from iTunesConnect.

Use the second link you showed. Also, you can go [here](https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/) to let Apple create the link if the app already exists.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So I use the one with "itms-apps:" instead of the one in the code right? My app is not in the app store yet.

Comment: My app is not in app store so I used both links and both links led me to same thing where it says my app isn't available in US stores. So what's the difference between both links when my app will be in App store?

Comment: I don't think there is a huge difference between them.